# Combine 2 Arrays Into 1 Datatable

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

I currently have two arrays which are being populated with information parallel to one another (i.e. array1[0] is a property of the item in array0[0], etc.). Ideally I would really like to combine these two arrays into one data table. I really need a data table as all of my other coding is dependent on one and would take too much time to restructure.

I've tried a few different loops to get the data into one table, but I'm interested in knowing if there is some kind of more efficient, less confusing code to do so.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dtExcel.Rows.Add(partsend[i], validationReturn[i]);
}
```

This code works perfectly fine, I'm just wondering if there is a different method. I've been learning quite a few new methods of development lately and I'm always interested in learning new things.

Comment: Have you considered a multi-dimensional array? Or a map from item in array0 to property in array1? That way you have one data structure.

Comment: So you already have a solution that's working, you just don't like it.  In that cast a) you should show us what you have if you expect us to compare ours to it b) you should be posting on Code Review, as SO is for code that's not working, not for code that *is* working.

Comment: Code is posted. Figured the loop was an easy enough one I didn't need to. Any different ideas?

Comment: Try looking at the [LoadDataRow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcy03ww2.aspx) method

Answer (score 0):

Zip will do something close to what you are asking, but most likely you should restructure your code to have properties of an object to be close associated with it (eisther directly on object or in some other structure that combines object and its extended properties).

Sample:

```
 var objectWithProperties = 
      array0.Zip(array1, (item, property)=> new {item, property});
```

Comment: This is a really interesting snippet, but it doesn't seem to be returning a usable data table. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Volearix - you need some particular type of collection as result? I guess I missed that from your post - no, this code will just combine your items into single sequence and not return a specific type you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I would like it to return as a DataTable object. It needs to be passed into another method for execution and it would take too long to modify that method to accept a different type of collection.